# QT library QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::finished() to MainWindow::updateGUI() Error

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am currently learning the QT Library as this seems to be a popular C++ GUI library. Previously, I as using wxWidgets which in some ways, I do like. But I have been finding that QT gives me more options in functionality and in some aspects is similar to wxWidgets.

Anyways, I am getting a strange error (which is the title of this post) where the code is unable to connect to my slot. At first, I thought that I was declaring my slot wrong. Then, it turns out that one of the QPushButton objects is interfering with the signal.

I have a Sequential Animation object where I am taking two buttons, having them fade out and then resizing the window. However, with this error, none of the animations are working. Until I comment out my QPushButton object. The odd part is that this object hasn't been allocated with space yet! The object is a pointer and I haven't declared it with new and I am getting this error.

The code is simple and I will be posting both the .h and .cpp files here. I will also be marking where the error occurs and where the objects are that are giving me the issue:

Here is the .h file

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QSequentialAnimationGroup *p_group;

//    QParallelAnimationGroup *p_parallelGroup;

    QPushButton *p_button; 

    QPushButton *p_anotherButton;

    QPushButton *p_backButton; // This is the object that when commented out, removes the error

    QPushButton *p_nextButton;

    QPushButton *p_finishButton;

    QPropertyAnimation *p_sizeAnimation;

    QPropertyAnimation *p_fadeOut;

    QGraphicsOpacityEffect *p_opacityEffect;

 //   QPushButton *p_backButton;

    systemState p_GUIState;



    void changeGUIState(systemState nextState);

 private slots:
    void handleButton();

    void hideOpenButton();

    void hideNewButton();

    void hideBackButton();

    void hideFinishButton();

    void updateGUI();
};
```

And here is the code in the .cpp file:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QHBoxLayout *startingLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    this->centralWidget()->setLayout(startingLayout);

    this->statusBar()->setSizeGripEnabled(false);

    this->statusBar()->setWindowTitle("Simulator");

    p_button = new QPushButton("New", this);
    p_anotherButton = new QPushButton("Open", this);


    this->centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(p_button);
    this->centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(p_anotherButton);

    this->setWindowTitle("Omni-FEM");
//    this->centralWidget()->layout()->children().at(1)
    this->setFixedSize(this->minimumSize());
//    p_anotherButton->setVisible(false);
//    this->setFixedSize(this->cenOpentralWidget()->size());

    connect(p_anotherButton, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (handleButton()));
}


void MainWindow::changeGUIState(systemState nextState)
{
    switch(nextState)
    {
        case systemState::PHYSICS_CHOOSING:
        {
            switch(p_GUIState)
            {
                case systemState::ON_START_UP_STATE:
                {
                    this->setMaximumSize(QSize(1000, 1000));

                    if(p_group)
                        delete p_group;

                    p_group = new QSequentialAnimationGroup;

                    p_sizeAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "size");
                    p_sizeAnimation->setDuration(500);
                    p_sizeAnimation->setStartValue(this->size());
                    p_sizeAnimation->setEndValue(QSize(600, 600));

                    p_opacityEffect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
                    QGraphicsOpacityEffect *test = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);

                    p_button->setGraphicsEffect(test);
                    p_anotherButton->setGraphicsEffect(p_opacityEffect);

                    QPropertyAnimation *fadeTest = new QPropertyAnimation(test, "opacity");

                    p_fadeOut = new QPropertyAnimation(p_opacityEffect, "opacity");
                    p_fadeOut->setDuration(1000);
                    p_fadeOut->setStartValue(1);
                    p_fadeOut->setEndValue(0);
                    p_fadeOut->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBack);

                    fadeTest = new QPropertyAnimation(test, "opacity");
                    fadeTest->setDuration(1000);
                    fadeTest->setStartValue(1);
                    fadeTest->setEndValue(0);
                    fadeTest->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBack);

                    p_fadeOut->start();
                    fadeTest->start();
             //       p_group->addAnimation(p_fadeOut);
             //       p_group->addAnimation(fadeTest);
                    p_group->addAnimation(p_sizeAnimation);

                    connect(p_fadeOut, SIGNAL (finished()), this, SLOT (hideOpenButton()));
                    connect(fadeTest, SIGNAL (finished()), this, SLOT (hideNewButton()));

                    p_group->start();

                }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    p_GUIState = nextState;
    connect(p_group, SIGNAL (finished()), this, SLOT (updateGUI())); // The Debugger throws the error on this line
}



// ----- Section is for Interrupts ------
void MainWindow::handleButton()
{
    changeGUIState(systemState::PHYSICS_CHOOSING);
}

void MainWindow::hideNewButton()
{
    p_button->setHidden(true);
}

void MainWindow::hideOpenButton()
{
    p_anotherButton->setHidden(true);
}

void MainWindow::hideBackButton()
{
}

void MainWindow::hideFinishButton()
{
}

void MainWindow::updateGUI()
{
    switch(p_GUIState)
    {
    case systemState::PHYSICS_CHOOSING:
        if(!p_finishButton)
        {
            p_finishButton = new QPushButton("Finish", this);
            this->centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(p_finishButton);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Here is the enum definition file:

```
//! The system state enum that describes the state that the UI is in
/*!
    This is used to keep track of what state that the UI is in. This will
    effect how frames are drawn and what variables are initilized or accessed.
    Some variables are accessed only when the user is drawing on the canvas,
    for example.
*/
enum class systemState
{
    ON_START_UP_STATE,/*!< The default value for the enum. This is the state that the program is in when the user first opens the progam in order to load any default settings */
    INITIAL_START_UP,/*!< This is the state that the program is in when the user can choose either new or open. The startup screen */
    PHYSICS_CHOOSING,/*!< This is the state that the program is in when the user can choose the simulation they would like to run */
    MODEL_DEFINING,/*!< This is the state that the program is in when the user is drawing their geometry on the canvas */
    SIMULATING,/*!< This is the state that the program is in when the user is simulating their simulation */
    VIEWING_RESULTS/*!< This is the state that the program is in when the user is viewing the results of the simulation */
};
```

Again, I am getting the error:

> QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::finished() to
>   MainWindow::updateGUI()

while I have the `QPushButton *p_button;` commented in. When commented out, the error goes away. I have tried placing the QPushButton in different spots in the code but I still receive the same error.

I am quite stumped by this error because I have not ran into anything similar to it! Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

BTW: I am using the latest released version of QT at the time of this writing. Additionally, for the animation of the two buttons fading, I was wanting to place them in a QParallelAnimationGroup but the samething is happening with the QParallelAnimationGroup as my QPushButton! Hence the reason is is commented out. So double points if you can suggest a fix for both issues! Which I think that issue with them is the same.

Comment: In what line does this error throw you?

Comment: I get this error when the application is running. This is not a compile error

Comment: but use a debugger, it tells you the line where the error is generated.

Comment: Sure, here is the line that that the error occurs: connect(p_group, SIGNAL (finished()), this, SLOT (updateGUI())); (For some reason, I can't make this into code format) I will be marking this in the source code. Whats odd is that the error might be occurring because the animation is not being setup. But how would the QPushButton be interferring with that?

Comment: change this line to: `if(p_group) connect(p_group, SIGNAL (finished()), this, SLOT (updateGUI()));`, it seems that p_group is null in some iteration

Comment: Yes, the p_group is null. That is very odd becuase the p_GUIState variable should be initialized to ON_START_UP_STATE value. How could the QPushButton be conflicting with that?

Comment: It is very difficult to trace the error with a lot of unnecessary code, and to tell you the truth, your code is not the most orderly one I have seen, it eliminates unnecessary things, it takes a coffee, and restructures your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because the p_group variable is null  when the connection is done. Perhaps `changeGUIState(systemState)` is invoked with `nextState != systemState::PHYSICS_CHOOSING` or that `p_GUIState != systemState::ON_START_UP_STATE`. Debug your program to find out!

Also I would recommend to use the new signal and slot syntax, example:

```
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, receiver, &Receiver::updateValue);
```

instead of

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(valueChanged(QString, QString)), receiver, SLOT( updateValue(QString)));
```

Why? The best reason being:

> Compile time check of the existence of the signals and slot, of the types, or if the Q_OBJECT is missing.

See https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax for more information.